# how to send the mail with out 200 error WSO2 iterate calling

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working with wso2 ESB 6.3.0
My complete functionality is:  make a call to a service rest api if getting any response to send the mail process was done but requriment is with out 200 status code remaimimg any status code sending the mail (ex: iam getting error code or success code to send send the mail reming 200 error code if any error code to send the mail.if any one please suggest me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/first" name="firston" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <property description="http" name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="404"/>
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="firstapi"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="200reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="200reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <case regex="400">
                    <log description="400log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="400reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="400reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="400reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <case regex="404">
                    <log description="404log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="404reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="404reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="404reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <case regex="500">
                    <log description="500log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="500reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="500reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="500reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>
            <clone continueParent="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <sequence key="sendthemail"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                <case regex="200">
                    <log description="200log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200errorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="200errormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="200httpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <case regex="400">
                    <log description="400log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="400errorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="400errormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="400httpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <case regex="404">
                    <log description="404log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="404errorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="404errormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="404httpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <case regex="500">
                    <log description="500log" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="500reserrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="500reserrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="500reshttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </case>
                <default>
                    <log description="faultlog" level="custom">
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="faulterrorcode"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="faulterrormessage"/>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="faulthttpsc"/>
                    </log>
                </default>
            </switch>
            <clone continueParent="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <sequence key="sendthemail"/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

ALL CODE IS WORKING ANY STATUS CODE 200 OR 404 OR 500 etc ANY STATUS CODE SEND THE MAIL MY REQUIREMENT IS  STATUS CODE !=200 REMAINING ANY STATUS CODE SEND THE MAIL PLEASE ANY ONE SUGGEST ME

Comment: The question asked is ambiguous , you need to simplify by asking in success what is the requirement and in failure what is the requirement, upon that your code is same for outsequence and fault sequence so it is untidy and difficult to read

Comment: i will update the code please check present this code is any status code ex:200 or 404 or 500 etc  send to the mail is done but my requirement is status code !=200 if  any other status code to send the mail @ amg_amit

Comment: Why can't you store the status code in a property mediator and then use filter to check if status code !=200 then send mail else don't do anything

Comment: i con't understand please explained or modified my code please suggest me@  amg_amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite simple, below is the code.

```
 <switch source="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')">
                    <case regex="200"><!-- Do not do anything here as it's success -->
                        <log description="200log" level="custom">
                            <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="200reserrorcode"/>

                        </log>
                    </case>

                    <default><!-- Put your logic here to send mail -->
                        <log description="reslog" level="custom">
                            <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_CODE" name="reserrorcode"/>
                            <property expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE" name="reserrormessage"/>
                            <property expression="get-property('axis2','HTTP_SC')" name="reshttpsc"/>
                        </log>
                    </default>
                </switch>
```

Comment: if any possible to write the condition   reshttpsc = 200 not send the mail reshttpsc = any other code to send the mail @ amg_amit